# Tera Term sending 8bit binary data

Tags: serial-port

I'm trying to use Tera Term to send binary data over the serial port.  When I try to send data that has the MSB = '1' Tera Term send multiple 8bit characters.  I've tried modifying the TERATERM.ini file as follows:

```
Meta8Bit=raw
Accept8BitCtrl=on
Send8BitCtrl=on
```

My .ttl script is very simple with the following loop just for testing purposes:

```
while 1
  send $80
  mpause 2      
endwhile
```

With the above script I get multiple 8bit character sends every 2ms - not 1 80hex send.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Change Language from UTF-8 to English

1. Setup --> General --> Language
2. Set to English
   Then you can send HEX >= 0x80

Answer (score 2):

You can do

```
while 1
  sendfile 'binaryfile' 1
  mpause 2      
endwhile
```

where `binaryfile` is a file that contains 0x80 in binary

This is a terrible work around, I wish I had a better solution.